# Cuando le doy a F5 a la página se desaparece el atributo user_name, saben como podría resolverlo ? Hace poco recién estoy iniciando con NuxtJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt

Tengo esta vista
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pero al recargarla desaparece este atributo que es el user_name
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo de componente padre

```
<div v-else>
  <div @click="showRegisterLogin">
    <resource-body :data="data">
      <resource-footer
        v-if="smallScreens.includes($mq)"
        :resource="data"
        :data-user="dataUser"
        :deleteable="deleteable"
        :list-user="listUser"
      />
    </resource-body>
    <a-divider />
  </div>
</div>
<resource-footer
  v-if="!smallScreens.includes($mq)"
  :resource="data"
  :data-user="dataUser"
  :options="options"
  :deleteable="deleteable"
  :list-user="listUser"
/>
...mapGetters({
  userFromId: 'user/fromId',
}),
dataUser() {
  const userFromStore = this.userFromId(this.data.user_id);
  return this.data.user || userFromStore;
},
```

Y este su método (el cual no entiendo muy bien)

```
dataUser() {
  const userFromStore = this.userFromId(this.data.user_id);
  return this.data.user || userFromStore;
},
```

Y este es el codigo hijo dónde lo está llamando al atributo user_name

```
<div class="user-options">
  <div class="user-info">
    <div class="user-avatar">
      <img :src="profileImg" alt="" @error="defaultImage">
    </div>
    <a :href="`/user/${(dataUser !== undefined ? dataUser.id : 
    null)}`">
      <span>{{ (dataUser !== undefined ? dataUser.user_name : "") 
      }}</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <DeleteFooterOption
    v-if="deleteable && userId === listUser"
    :resource="resource"
  />
</div>
```

AL entra e iniciar sesion si lo muestra ese atributos en el footer del card pero después de recargar la página ya no :(. No sé como solucionarlo ...

Aparentemente el problema está aquí que se encuentra dentro de la carpeta store/ el archivo es user.js

```
export const getters = {
  fromId: state => id => state.users[id],
};
```

el cual me parece que lo está usando en el componente padre
Cuando trata de imprimir lo que está en user.js me bota indefinido
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]